# SQL- Simple but tricky query challenge

Tags: sql, sql-server, join

i ran into this challenge earlier today.

Write an sQL query to:
Keep the newest version of each record using `date_added` but
Keep the oldest `this_flag` value. 
Only `[Name]`,`[DOB]` and `[ID]` are used to determine uniqueness of a record

```
CREATE TABLE [Table C](
    [Date_added] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [this_flag] [varchar](1) NULL,
    [Name] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [DOB] [int] NULL,
    [ID] [int] NULL) ;

Date_added  this_flag       Name                DOB         ID
20150501    Y               Jingleheimerscmidt  19901002    3
20150501    N               Jingleheimerscmidt  19901002    3
20150505    Y               Jon                 19901001    1
20150501    N               Jon                 19901002    1
20150501    Y               Jacob               19901001    2
20150505    N               Jingleheimerscmidt  19901001    3
20150501    Y               Jingleheimerscmidt  19901001    3
```

This is what I did

```
SELECT * FROM Table_C where ID < 3;
```

I know the logic is not correct. But all the other syntaxes just
did not cut it.
Does anyone know how to write a correct SQL query for this?

Comment: what output do you want ? question is unclear

Comment: The output will be a SQL query that (1) shows the newest version of each record using date_added and (2) Keep the oldest this_flag value.Using only [Name],[DOB] and [ID] to determine unique record records

Comment: can you please post the output ? what you mean by flag

Comment: which is the oldest flag

Comment: Something doesn't add up here. If Name, dob and id should be unique, your sample data is incorrect - first 2 records are duplicatets, and last 2 records are also duplicates.

Comment: Read, @ZoharPeled, slowly and carefully. No one said those have to be unique. The statement declares that those 3 columns are used to DETERMINE uniqueness. If you read English, that is clear

Comment: Here is the output @mohan     20150505    Y               Jon                 19901001    1
20150501    N               Jon                 19901002    1
20150501    Y               Jacob               19901001    2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this out (Assumes you have SQL Server Version 2012 or higher)

Tt uses the Analytics function First_Val to get the oldest record for "this_flag" column and the Rank function to rank based on descending order of date added so that the latest date always comes in with a  rank=1

```
SELECT * from 
(
    Select * , FIRST_VALUE(this_flag) OVER (PArtition By Name, ID Order by Date_Added ) FirstVal_this_flag 
    , RANK() OVER ( PArtition By Name, ID Order by Date_Added desc ) as Rnk
    from Table_C C 
) a
Where Rnk = 1
```

Edit: The First 2 rows in your sample have the same **date_Added** value and their **Pk's are also identical.** Perhaps this is a typo in your question but in any case this Query below will handle that situation too. It just takes the 1st this_flag returned by the SQL Engine after sorting by Date_Added.

```
SELECT Distinct Date_Added , Name, DoB, ID, FirstVal_this_flag from 
(
    Select * , FIRST_VALUE(this_flag) OVER (PArtition By Name, DoB, ID Order by Date_Added ) FirstVal_this_flag 
    , RANK() OVER ( PArtition By Name, DoB, ID Order by Date_Added desc ) as Rnk
    from Table_C C 
) a
Where Rnk = 1
```

Comment: Thank you @objectNotFound. This time 'the object is found' - This syntax works. I worked on this logic, trying to make it work; but it was tricky. I did a SELECT statement and produced the output desired. However, the logic still eluded me. Adding the rnk column is quite helpful. I was leaning towards doing a SELF-JOIN. I appreciate your insight

Comment: @Koda you are most welcome. Plus 1 for posing a tricky question. I liked working on this.